# Why my $scope is not accessible in my controller - Angular JS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am not able to get declared scope variable in my controller. Instead I'm getting `reference error : message is not defined`

Below is my code:

My Index.html

```
<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="homingController" ng-cloak>
<script type="text/javascript">
    angular.module('myApp' ['ngRoute','ngMaterial']).controller('homingController', ['$scope',

    function($scope){
        $scope.message = 'Hello';
    }
  ]).config(function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.when("/home", {
        templateUrl: "home.html",
        controller: "homingController"
    }).when("/monitor", {
        templateUrl: "monitor.html",
        controller: "monitoringController"
    }).otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/home'
    });
 }).controller('monitoringController', function ($scope) {
    $scope.message = "Monitor";
});
</script>

<nav class = "navbar navbar-inverse" role="navigation">
    <ul class = "nav navbar-nav"  >
        <li ><a href="#!/home" class = "active" ui-sref= "home" style="margin: 0px 1px 0px 19px"><img src="./images/home.svg">Home</a></li>
        <li ><a href="#!/monitor" class = "active" ui-sref = "monitor" ><img src="./images/monitor.svg">Monitor</a></li>
        <li ><a class = "active" ui-sref = "Audit" ><img src="./images/audit.svg">Audit</a></li>
        <li ><a class = "active" ui-sref = "configuration" ><img src="./images/configure.svg">Configure</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
</div>
</body>
<div ng-view></div>
```

My home.html

```
{{ message}}  
/*This line giving error in console : angular.js:14328 ReferenceError: $scope is not defined
*/
```

Is there anything I am missing here?

Comment: Yes...you are missing a [mcve] that reproduces the problem

Comment: what more should i need to add ?

Comment: where is your `angular.js` script

Comment: In Local, I have added this in index.html

Comment: where? it's not the html file

Comment: Plz check now !! It was editing issue

Comment: What's doing the `homingController`as controller in the body tag? 

`<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="homingController" ng-cloak>`

You're already using it in the view and route definitions...

Comment: Can you plz update what to change ?

Comment: IDK :D try removing it from that tag

Comment: Can you remove all the stuff that we don't need, at least? Like most of those imports, the images and the styling, seeing as the question is only about a controller displaying a message. Just show us the bit of code that is throwing the error and everything relevant to that.

Answer (score 1):

Your `<div ng-view></div>` should be inside your `<body>` tag. By placing it outside of the body, in which you define your app, the views have no idea what app or controller they should be using.

You also don't need to identify `ng-controller`'s anywhere around your views, since you define them in your routeconfig:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp' ['ngRoute']);

app.config(function($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider
    .when("/home", {
      templateUrl: "home.html",
      controller: "homingController"
    }).when("/monitor", {
      templateUrl: "monitor.html",
      controller: "monitoringController"
    }).otherwise({
      redirectTo: '/home'
    });
});

app.controller('homingController', function($scope) {
  $scope.message = 'Hello';
})

app.controller('monitoringController', function($scope) {
  $scope.message = "Monitor";
});
```

If you want to display something from one of your controllers you should define it like so:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-app="myApp">

  <div ng-controller="homingController">
    {{message}}
  </div>

  <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse" role="navigation">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li>
        <a href="#!/home">Home</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#!/monitor">Monitor</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>

  <div ng-view></div>

</body>
```

With your `home.html` & `monitor.html` containing `{{ message }}`. An exact example of this can be found at [w3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/angular/angular_routing.asp) (Under the heading "Controllers"). Build that, then once you have that working start expanding on it to fill in the rest of your application.